# usb0 problems with raspberry pi

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi

i have recently bought a raspberry pi so i can learn "linux" and other stuff with it, i loaded it with noobs and add raspbian and ubuntu mate ([this](http://forum.xda-developers.com/raspberry-pi/development/ubuntumate-port-noobs-t3267928) port from xda forums) and everything works well. than i decided to try and use vnc to have my phone (Galaxy s3) be used as the display. i tried to follow [this](http://joshuawoehlke.com/android-raspberry-pi-display-over-usb/) tutorial but after i boot the pi and run ifconfig (both when the phone is and isn't connected) i can't see usb0

so after further investigation when i run ifup usb0 i get "cannot find device usb0", does anyone no a solution?

note (i have tried this with ubuntu mate and have yet to try with raspbian)

Comment: I have to know which distrubtion you used exactly. Raspian based on debian 10? If you connect your phone to your raspberry, is `usb0` listed as interface under `ifconfig`? (or just add the whole output of `ip a` to your question - that could be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I will explain it a little bit more in detail because we need some clarification here. 
The technique which is used in your tutorial is called USB tethering where you share a network connection over an USB-Cable.

What you are trying to do is to set an address to a usb node (named `usb0`). *Maybe this step isn't necessary because the android device may provide dhcp*

The usbX interface typically shows up after connecting your phone to your raspberry. Be sure you set up **"USB Tethering" and "USB Debugging"** correctly on your phone (I could not provide any steps here because this setting depends on your android version).

Check your progress with `ip a`.

If you see the `usb0`interface you are ready to assign an address to it:

**/etc/dhcpcd.conf**

```
interface usb0
static ip_address=192.168.1.XX/24
static routers=192.168.1.1
static domain_name_servers=192.168.1.1
```

(Source of the network configuration with more examples and methods:  https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/37920/how-do-i-set-up-networking-wifi-static-ip-address/74428#74428